# Was bedeutet »im Allgemeinen gilt«?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Wenn man sagt:

> Im Allgemeinen gilt (a+b)² ≠ a² + b².

stimmt das dann? Ich würde »im Allgemeinen« als »für alle a,b« interpretieren, die Aussage wäre demzufolge nach meinem Verständnis falsch (weil a = b = 0 ein Gegenbeispiel ist). Ich bin mir aber ziemlich sicher, dass ich die trotzdem Aussage schonmal so in der Art gehört habe. Derjenige meinte dann bestimmt mit »im Allgemeinen«, dass (a+b)² ≠ a² + b² in der Regel gilt und es nur sehr wenige Ausnahmen gibt.

Nun meine Frage: Wie ist »im Allgemeinen«" zu verstehen? Bedeutet es »für alle a, b« oder bedeutet es »in der Regel gilt für a, b, dass (a+b)² ≠ a² + b²; es gibt nur sehr wenige Ausnahmen«"?

Comment: "Im allgemeinen überlebt man den dritten Herzinfarkt nicht" sollte ein Beispiel "aus dem echten Leben" sein. Es heißt nicht, dass man dann automatisch tot ist - aber mit sehr hoher statistischer Wahrscheinlichkeit.

Comment: *Im Allgemeinen* und *grundsätzlich* deuten beide an, dass es Ausnahmen gibt, die an jener Stelle aber nicht erörtert werden sollen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### im Allgemeinen

Bedeutet: Die Aussage ist, so wie es da steht, eigentlich fast immer wahr. Aber es gibt ein paar spezielle Ausnahmen, wo das dann doch nicht der Fall ist.

In dem im Beispiel genannten Fall, muss das Ungleichkeitszeiche durch ein Gleichheitszeichen ersetzt werden, wenn a oder b (oder beide) den Wert 0 annehmen.

»Im Allgemeinen« bedeutet: wenn du für a und b *irgendwelche* Zahlen einsetzt, dann ist die dargestellte Aussage in den meisten Fällen wahr.

Man verwendet diese Ausdrucksweise um zu sagen:

> Gehe nicht davon aus, dass **(a+b)²** dasselbe wie **a² + b²** ergibt. Das kann zwar in einigen besonderen Fällen durchaus mal so sein. Aber in den vielen nicht-besonderen Fällen (also »im Allgemeinen«) kommen zwei verschiedene Ergebnisse heraus.

Answer (score 5):

Das ist eine mathematische Ausdrucksweise, die ich auch etwas unglücklich finde, die aber nicht unüblich ist. Es ist lediglich gemeint, dass *(a+b)² = a² + b²* nicht allgemein (also nicht für alle a, b) gilt.

Comment: (a+b)² = a² + b² gilt sogar nicht nur nicht allgemein, sondern fast nie :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, richtig, für generische a, b gilt Gleichheit nicht ;) Das ist hier aber meiner Meining nach nicht der Punkt.

Comment: Ich wollte eher darauf raus, ob es in deinem letzten Satz nicht auch "≠" heißen muss. ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, nein. Meine Aussage ist, dass der Satz aus der Frage lediglich besagt, dass die beiden Seiten nicht immer gleich sind.

Comment: Hm. Ich sehe das eher so, dass die Aussage in der Frage bedeutet, dass beide Seiten bis auf wenige, nicht genannte Ausnahmefälle, normalerweise *nicht gleich* sind - nämlich nur genau dann, wenn a = 0 oder b = 0.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, und ich sehe das anders, ich erkenne in der Aussage noch keine Information dazu, wie wichtig oder häufig die Fälle sind, in denen Gleichheit gilt.

Comment: Naja, "im Allgemeinen" bedeutet ja, dass dieser Fall der gängige ist, d.h. dass davon die Mehrzahl der Fälle abgedeckt ist.

Comment: @CarstenS: Sei P(x) eine Aussageform mit der freien Variablen x. Dann sagt man also, dass "P(x) im allgemeinen gilt", wenn es ein x mit P(x) gibt?

Comment: @Nullachtfünfzehn, nein, das meinte ich nicht. "P(x) gilt allgemein" kann eigentlich nur heißen, dass es für alle x gilt. Dann sagt man aber manchmal (und das ist der unglückliche Teil) "im allgemeinen gilt ¬P(x)" und meint "P(x) gilt nicht allgemein", obwohl das eigentlich falsch ist.

Answer (score 4):

Man muss in der mathematischen Sprache zwei Formulierungen unterscheiden:

**Ohne Beschränkung der Allgemeinheit**
Bedeutet, dass eine Aussage auch ohne eine im konkreten Fall/Beweis getroffene Einschränkung gültig ist. Häufig trifft man auf diese Formulierung im Rahmen von Beweisen, wo man ggf. je nach Beweisverfahren eine einschränkende Annahme trifft, der Beweis aber auch ohne diese Einschränkung äquivalent für alle anderen Fälle auch gilt.

**Im Allgemeinen**
Bedeutet nichts anderes als, "für die meisten Fälle, aber nicht für alle". Üblicherweise werden die Ausnahmen dann genannt. Das Beispiel von Dir gilt eben "im Allgemeinen" schon, aber "im Besonderen", dem Fall a = 0 oder b = 0 eben nicht.

Answer (score 2):

"Im Allgemeinen gilt" kann man sinngemäß übersetzen mit

*In den meisten Fällen gilt*

*Für fast alle a,b gilt*

*Es gibt (vernachlässigbar) seltene Ausnahmen*

Dein letzter Satz, "in der Regel gilt für a, b, dass (a+b)² ≠ a² + b²; es gibt nur sehr wenige Ausnahmen", ist eine richtige Interpretation.

Comment: *"Im Allgemeinen gilt"* und *"für fast alle x gilt"* sollte man
nicht in einen Topf werfen.
Während die erste Formulierung eher informell gebraucht wird,
hat die zweite eine klar definierte Bedeutung
(je nach Fachgebiet *"die Menge der Ausnahmen ist endlich"* oder *"die Menge der Ausnahmen hat das Maß Null"*).

Comment: @Uwe "die Menge der Ausnahmen hat das Maß Null" wäre "Für alle a,b gilt".
"Für fast alle a,b gilt" bedeutet lediglich, dass es minimum _eine_ Ausnahme gibt. _Im Allgemeinen_, so gebe ich dir recht, ist informell. Ich denke aber, dass es um das generelle Verständniss der Aussage geht, und nicht um die Mathematische Präzision, die bei mittelmäßigem Verständnis der deutschen Sprache (bitte nicht als _herabwertend_ interpretieren!) nicht gegeben sein muss

Comment: Du verwechselst gerade "eine Menge hat das Maß Null" und
"eine Menge ist leer". Die Kollegen von Mathematics.SE erklären Dir gerne den Unterschied.

Comment: Im genannten Beispiel gibt es unendlich viele Ausnahmefälle. Daher sind weder »Für fast alle .. gilt« noch »Es gibt vernachlässigbar seltene Ausnahmen« angebrachte Erklärungen.

Comment: Also wenn ich nicht ganz falsch liege gibt es genau drei Ausnahmefälle, nämlich a = 0 oder b = 0...?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Na ja, die Menge der Ausnahmefälle, also { (a,b) ∈ ℝ² | a = 0 oder b = 0 },
ist in der Tat (überabzählbar) unendlich. Sie besitzt aber im
zweidimensionalen Raum die Fläche (d.h., das Maß) 0,
also ist die Aussage "*für fast alle a,b gilt (a + b)² ≠ a² + b²*" schon mathematisch korrekt.

Comment: Die Anzahl der möglichen Kombinationen, so dass a=0 oder b=0 ist unendlich, das stimmt. Dennoch ist die Anzahl der Kriterien zwei. Es wäre ja redundant, alle unendlich vielen Elemente als Ausnahmen auszuführen, wenn es genügt, die einzigen beiden relevanten Kriterien zu nennen.

Comment: Man würde ja auch sagen "für alle  (a,b) ∈ ℝ² mit a ≠ 0 und b ≠ 0 gilt: (a + b)² ≠ a² + b²" anstatt die entsprechende Menge aufzuzählen.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Charakteristik-2-Körper. Da gilt es immer.

Comment: Bis auf den unbegründeten Begriff *vernachlässigbar* könnte ich zustimmen.

Answer (score 1):

Dies ist eine informelle Sprechweise, die Mathematiker mitunter benutzen. Beispiel: Du hältst einen Vortrag und erwähnst solch eine Formel, wie in Deinem Beispiel -- oder irgendetwas nicht ganz so Triviales. Dann bedeutet im Allgemeinen, daß es Ausnahmen gibt, die aber offensichtlich oder uninteressant sind. Das hat aber nichts mit Wahrscheinlichkeit oder Vernachlässigbarkeit zu tun.

Wenn man einen mathematischen Text schreibt, ist zu empfehlen, solch eine Formulierung nicht zu verwenden, sondern genau anzugeben, was die Ausnahmen sind, und das machen die Mathematiker routinemäßig.

Answer (score 0):

Normale Menschen verstehen unter "Im Allgemeinen" das gleiche wie "Im Normalfall" oder "In der Regel". Mathematiker benutzen "Im Allgemeinen" mit der Bedeutung "In größerer Allgemeinheit". "Die Aussage ist im Allgemeinen falsch" bedeutet also nicht, dass sie fast nie gilt, sondern dass sie falsch wird, wenn man eine Voraussetzung wegläßt.

Beispiel: Jede endliche Gruppe erfüllt ... . Diese Aussage ist im Allgemeinen falsch. Olshanski zeigte 1979, dass es eine unendliche Gruppe gibt, so dass ... .

Comment: Und wie ist das nun auf die Aussage aus der Frage anzuwenden?

Comment: @Carsten S: Die Bedeutung der Aussage hängt von dem Sprecher und der Sprachsituation ab. In einer Vorlesung für Erstsemestler gilt die zweite Interpretation, wenn ein Schüler einem anderen die Hausaufgaben erklärt, die erste. Wenn ein Mathematiker einem Schüler die Hausaufgaben erklärt, ist nicht klar was gemeint ist. Dieses Problem tritt immer auf, wenn ein Begriff in einer Fachsprache anders benutzt wird als in der allgemeinen Sprache, also z.B. auch wenn ein Musiker von klassischer Musik oder ein Jurist von grundsätzlich verbotenen Dingen redet.